# Executing remote commands with sshsession Ant task

Tags: ant

I'm having issues with [sshsession](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshsession.html) Ant task.

I'm writing a deploy script which bzip sources, scp the archive to a remote server and then unzip sources on the remote server and copy files in the right directory tree.

```
(...)

<bzip2 src="/tmp/${selected.target}.tar" destfile="/tmp/${selected.target}.tar.bz2"/>
<scp file="/tmp/${selected.target}.tar.bz2" todir="user@server:/tmp/" keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa" trust="yes" passphrase="thisisasecret"/>

<sshsession host="server" username="user" keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa" trust="yes">
    <sequential>
        <untar src="/tmp/${selected.target}.tar.bz2" dest="/tmp/prova_untar" compression="bzip2"/>
        (copy files)
    </sequential>
</sshsession>

(...)
```

My problem is with tasks specified inside the sshsession, since they are executed locally and not on the remote server. I thought (but clearly i'm wrong) that command specified within sshsession tag would be executed on the server i just connected to. I read in the documentation that you can specify tunnels with localtunnel and remotetunnel, but i'm not sure i'm understanding correctly what those tunnels are for. Does anyone has encountered the same problem, or has a solution for that? The Ant version i'm working with is 1.8.2.
Thanks,

Alberto

Comment: i think you need to use [sshexec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html). sshsession seems to be for connection tunneling and not for reomote execution.

Comment: Thanks oers. I've chosen sshsession because i need to execute a list of remote commands, and sshexec just opens a new session everytime..

Comment: We have the similar situation -- to execute a list of remote commands, and what we do is to write a "remote-build.xml" and copy it together with other files to the remote machine. Of course we have to install ant in the remote machine but I think that is just OK.

Comment: Localtunnel is to forward a local port to a remote port, so that you can use localhost:localport to connect to remotehost:remoteport in your local applications. Remotetunnel is reversed. It forwards your local port to a remote port so that when you want a remote application to connect to one port in your machine and you don't want to set exception in your firewall, neither put the ssh certificate needed to the remotehost. For ant tasks, many of them are written in pure java (just extending ant's task class) so that they should not be able to run remotely with sshsession.

Comment: Thanks @coolcfan! In the meanwhile i solved my problem by using sshexec with a plain list of commands (divided by a semicolon) - this is awkward, but it just works. Your approach seems much cleaner, i'll give it a try.

Comment: Happy to see you solve that~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add a answer to show how we use the remote-build.xml.

For example, we want to deploy some pre-built SQL files to the database server, insert the sql files into a database in MySQL and restart mysql.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="remote-build" basedir=".">

    <target name="run">
        <antcall target="extract" />
        <antcall target="build-database" />
        <antcall target="restart-mysql" />
    </target>

    <target name="extract">
        <unzip src="sample-sql.zip" dest="."/>
    </target>

    <target name="build-database">
        <taskdef name="insert" classname="my.company.ant.ParallelInsertSQL" classpath="my-company-lib.jar"/>
        <insert dbName="${database.name}" masterSQLs="${basedir}/sample-sql.sql" sqlDir="${basedir}/tables"/>
        <antcall target="restart-database"/>
    </target>

    <target name="restart-database">
        <exec executable="bash" inputstring="echo '${database.password}' | sudo -S /etc/init.d/mysql restart"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

So when deploying, we packed the sql file archive (sample-sql.zip) together with "my-company-lib.jar" and "remote-build.xml" and then transfer the archive file with `scp`.
Then, sshexec "ant -f remote-build.xml run" (you can either put the properties in a properties file or transfer them in the sshexec commandline).

Comment: nice workaround, unfortunately you will have to install ant on the remote machine and thats not always possible in production environment etc. i think `sshsession` task is misleading by that it doesn't perform what you expect it to do which is run ant tasks remotely. I wonder if there is a task or lib that is able to achieve  this goal, as it will make stuff much cleaner than using shell commands with `sshexec`

Comment: @michael If ant is not installed on the target machine, then we can deploy something else, like windows batch file, or linux shell script... I think it's hard to execute ant tasks remotely -- it should require an installed ant, too.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is not exactly new, I found myself in a similar situation today. My goal is to upload files and run commands on a remote server to which I have to tunnel (through another server). The answer given (requiring ant on the remote server) is totally unacceptable for me, but the comments here helped me forge this solution

The `sshsession` only creates a **tunnel** that you can use for the tasks within. The tasks within are not automatically run on the remote server but you can use the `sshexec` task together with the **tunnel** to achieve that. Also the `scp` task can now upload through the tunnel to the remote server. Here is an example:

```
<sshsession host="${jumphost}" port="22" username="${user}" password="${password}" trust="true">
    <localtunnel lport="${localTunnelPort}" rhost="${targethost}" rport="22"/>
    <sequential>
        <!-- run a command on the remote server (here mkdir) -->
        <sshexec host="localhost" port="${localTunnelPort}" username="${user.param}" password="${password.param}" command="mkdir ${home}/foobar" trust="true" />
        <!-- upload a file to the remote server -->
        <scp port="${localTunnelPort}" file="test_file.txt" todir="${user.param}:${password.param}@localhost:${home}/foobar/" trust="true" />
    </sequential>
</sshsession>
```